# Multiple inheritance with multiple parents

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

**Base** is superclass.
It has instance variable= **sides**.
It has **show()** method which gives value of **sides**.

**Circle** inherits **Base**.
It has **show()** method which prints classname.

**Triangle** inherits **Base**.
It has **show()** method which prints classname.

**Square** inherits **Base**.
It has **show()** method which prints classname.

**Shape** inherits **Circle**,**Triangle**,**Square**.
It has **show()** method which prints "i'm in shape"

We have to create an instance of the **Shape** class and access the **show()** method of **Circle** class using the instance created.

I want to access the **show()** method of **Circle** only and not the **show()** method of the **Shape** class.

How do I do that?

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self,sides):
        self.sides=sides

    def show(self):
        return self.sides

class Triangle(Base):
    def show(self):
        print("Triangle")

class Square(Base):
    def show(self):
        print("Square")

class Circle(Base):
    def show(self):
        print("Circle")

class Shape(Circle,Square,Triangle):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Shape,self).show()
    def show(self):
        print("i am in shape")

a=Shape()
a.show()
```

*I was trying to get the output as:*

```
Circle
```

*But the code is giving me the output as:*

```
Circle
i am in shape
```

how does the code change if i have to call show method of  Circle class by a.show() by using the instance of Shape class?

Comment: So why are you calling `a.show()` as well as `super(Shape,self).show()` in `__init__`?

Comment: Calling `a=Shape()` will call the constructor, and will print `Circle`, why the extra `a.show()`?

Comment: @Martjin Pieters i was thinking if i could access the show method of Circle by writing a.show()

Comment: Check if my answer below makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should leave the `super(Shape,self).show()` as it is and just instantiate the `Shape`, which will print `Circle` as below. The exta `a.show()` you are calling is printing the extra `i am in shape`

```
class Shape(Circle,Square,Triangle):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Shape,self).show()

    def show(self):
        print("i am in shape")

#The constructor is called
a=Shape()
#Circle

#The show function of class Shape is called
a.show()
#i am in shape
```

If you want to explicitly access the `show` method of `Circle`, you need to instantiate that object.

```
a=Circle(2)
a.show()
#Circle
```

In addition, look at: [How does Python's super() work with multiple inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277367/how-does-pythons-super-work-with-multiple-inheritance) for more info on how super works for multiple inheritance

Comment: how do i call the show method of Circle class by writing a.show()?

Comment: how does the code change if i have to call show method of  Circle class by a.show()?

Comment: By explicitly creating the object of class Circle!

Comment: is it possible to call the show method of Circle by making instance of Shape and then accessing by a.show()

Comment: No, since `a.show()` calls the show method of Shape, and not Circle!

Comment: Great! Please accept the answer if it helped you :)